# nodejs file system does not read file after first http response

Tags: node.js

i am making a simple `http` `node.js` server, by just making it send the most common files on web (`HTML`, `JavaScript`, `CSS`).

so i just make the node files and test for only `HTML` file which is just fine, but when i try to make it send `JavaScript` or `CSS` file, the server returns an error and closes.

main.js

```
/*
*   Main node.js server file
*/

// Load all modules
console.log('Loading modules');
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    file = require('./bin/file.js');

// Load config file
console.log('Loading configuration file');
var config = fs.readFileSync('./config.json');
var config = JSON.parse(config);

// Config http server
var host = http.createServer(function(request, response)
{
    console.log('requesting: ', request.url);

    var view = file.read(request.url);

    response.writeHead(view.status, view.head);
    response.write(view.content);
    response.end();
});

// Start server
if(host.listen(config.port))
    console.log('Http server initialized on port:', config.port);
```

just in case, config.json contains only the port and web files directory

file.js

```
// Load the required modules
var fs = require('fs');

// Load configuration
var config = fs.readFileSync('config.json');
var config = JSON.parse(config);

// Export module function
module.exports = {
    read: function(file)
    {
        if(file == '/')
            return loadFile('/index.html');
    }
};

// Load the requested file
function loadFile(file)
{
    var req = fs.readFileSync(config.dirFiles + file);

    var result = {};

    if(!req)
    {
        result = {
            status: 404,
            head: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'},
            content: 'The requested view does not exist'
        };
    }

    else
    {
        result = {
            status: 200,
            head: {'Content-Type': getMIME(file)},
            content: req
        };
    }

    return result;
}

// Detect MIME file type
function getMIME(file)
{
    var regex = /(.css|.html|.js)/;
    var ext = regex.exec(file);

    var MIME = '';

    switch(ext[1])
    {
        case '.js':
            MIME = 'text/javascript';
            break;

        case '.css':
            MIME = 'text/css';
            break;

        case '.html':
            MIME = 'text/html';
            break;
    }

    return MIME;
}
```

on requesting a `CSS` file, the server tells that view.status property is undefined, this might be because the file is being read `synchronous` but i don't know what other way i would do

Comment: shouldn't you return `loadFile(file)` if `file === '/'` is not true?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here but the main issue is that you're only ever reading in `index.html`. So when the request path doesn't match `/`, `undefined` is returned from `read()`. Then in your request handler you essentially try reading `undefined.status` which obviously doesn't exist.

Another issue is that you really shouldn't do synchronous reads like that. Not only is the usage incorrect (the `fs.*Sync` methods *throw exceptions* instead of returning a false-y value on any kind of error -- including "file not found" errors), but doing it asynchronously provides better concurrency since you're not blocking other requests until your file read is done.

A third issue is that your `getMIME()` doesn't return a default mime type, in case the requested file does not match any of the supported extensions.

Here is one example solution that solves the previously mentioned issues:

**main.js:**

```
// ...

var host = http.createServer(function(request, response)
{
    console.log('requesting: ', request.url);

    var view = file.read(request.url);

    response.writeHead(view.status, view.head);
    if (view.stream)
      view.stream.pipe(response);
    else
      response.end(view.content);
});

// ...
```

**file.js:**

```
var path = require('path');

// ...

module.exports = {
    read: function(file)
    {
        if (file == '/')
            return loadFile('/index.html');
        return loadFile(file);
    }
};

// Load the requested file
function loadFile(file)
{
    var loc = path.normalize(config.dirFiles + file);
    // check for malicious requests to files outside of `config.dirFiles`
    if (loc.indexOf(config.dirFiles) === 0 && fileExists(loc)) {
      return {
        status: 200,
        head: {'Content-Type': getMIME(file)},
        stream: fs.createReadStream(loc)
      };
    }
    return {
      status: 404,
      head: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'},
      content: 'The requested view does not exist'
    };
}

// Detect MIME file type
function getMIME(file)
{
    var regex = /(.css|.html|.js)/;
    var ext = regex.exec(file);

    var MIME = '';

    switch(ext[1])
    {
        case '.js':
            MIME = 'text/javascript';
            break;

        case '.css':
            MIME = 'text/css';
            break;

        case '.html':
            MIME = 'text/html';
            break;

        default:
            MIME = 'text/plain';
    }

    return MIME;
}

function fileExists(filename) {
  try {
    var stats = fs.statSync(filename);
    return stats.isFile();
  } catch (ex) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: i never understood about pipe methods

Comment: although i just saw why it wasn't sending any other file, but i will investigate about pipe, never understood it but if it's the best way, i should do it